# three.js changing texture crash on mobile - context lost

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js

I have been working on a tree.js project, with a simple model.
I try to change the colors by changing the map texture.

on mobile phones, especially iPhones, the WebGL crashes after 3-4 colors (map texture) changes.
on the PC browser, it works well (although if you change the texture many times fast enough it will also crash).

please see the model here: https://combie-web.herokuapp.com/ (you can change colors with the color icon BTN on the right)

the only error I get after a crash is: (on the PC)

> webgl: context_lost_webgl: losecontext: context lost

the model build by 6 objects that all has the same map (each object knows what part of the map to use).

I am changing the texture of only one of the objects by using TextureLoader:

```
//g_Body declare on scene load
var g_Body = scene.getObjectByName("Body");

...

var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
// load a resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    `static/Color/${color}/Combie_Combie_Diffuse.png`,
    // Function when resource is loaded
    function ( texture ) {
      // apply the new texture to the model body map
      g_Body.material.map = texture;
      g_Body.material.needsUpdate = true;
    },
    // Function called when download progresses
    function ( xhr ) {
      console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
    },
    // Function called when download errors
    function ( xhr ) {
      console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
);
```

Comment: Each texture loading add 64Mo usage in Gpu Vram (4k rgba). You just run out of memory. Dispose old textures.

Comment: how do I dispose the old textures?

Comment: i did `g_Body.material.map.dispose();` and i worked! fixed the problem on most of the mobile phones. but still, we have some crashes at iPhone with older ios version... :/ any idea on how to debug this?